# Dispose called in Form

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a Form based application, which contains user controls in tabs. One of the user control has a grid. A popup is displayed to modify certain values of the grid. If we click the OK button of the popup, Dispose is called on the Form. The problem is present in Win Xp 64 bit. It is working fine in WIn XP 32 bit.

How can I know that which portion is calling Dispose of the Form? How can I correct the issue?

Comment: So what is the problem?  What does your click handler for your ok button look like?  How can we possibly know what your problem is when there is no code to look at?

Comment: Can you please clearly elaborate your question so that it will be helpful on the reader. May I know how did you call your popup controls? Is it a new form? and upon calling the popup control, is the main window is retained or hidden?

Comment: Is there an unhandled exception letting the app crash?

Comment: See if you have your event handler code under Using(){} block or explicit Dispose call. Dispose is always explicit call. Run time never invokes it automatically unless used in Using(){} blocks or iterators over collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out who calls `Dispose()` on your form by setting a breakpoint on the `Dispose()` method of your form, attach the debugger, click at on the OK button and when the breakpoint gets hit look at the callstack.